# Best practices for passing in API key in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-view-controller, api-key

I am working on a simple weather dashboard in ASP.NET core with MVC. I have figured out how to pass the URI base address for the weather API call from the appsettings to the configuration settings and then to the interface which calls the weather API:

appsettings:

```
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      //Here:
      "openWeatherAPI": "https://api.openweathermap.org/",
    }
```

startup configuration:

```
   

 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Here
            string uri = Configuration.GetValue<string>("openWeatherAPI");

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddHttpClient<IForecastRepository, ForecastRepository>(c =>  
                {
                    //And Here:
                    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
                }
                );
```

Forecast Interface:

```
 

    public interface IForecastRepository
        {
            Task<CityModel> GetMovieDetailsAsync(string cityName);
        }
    
        public class ForecastRepository : IForecastRepository
        {     
                private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    
            public ForecastRepository(HttpClient httpClient)
                {
                    _httpClient = httpClient;       
            }
    
    
            public async Task<CityModel> GetMovieDetailsAsync(string cityName)
            {
                string IDOWeather = "/*my api key is hardcoded in here*/";
                var queryString = $"data/2.5/weather?q={cityName}&units=imperial&APPID={IDOWeather}";
                var response = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(queryString);
    
             //...code conitnues
```

Is there a similar way I can pass in the API key? It's my understanding that it is not considered best practice to have it written into the app where I do.

For discussion of HttpClientFactory:

WeatherController:

```
    public class WeatherController : Controller
    {


        private readonly IForecastRepository _forecastRepository;
        
        public WeatherController(IForecastRepository forecastRepository)
        {
            _forecastRepository = forecastRepository;
        }

        public IActionResult SearchCity()
        {
            var viewModel = new CityModel();
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        public IActionResult City()
        {
            var viewModel = new CityModel();
            return View(viewModel);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SearchResults(CityModel titleFromView)
        {

            var movieDetail = await _forecastRepository.GetMovieDetailsAsync(titleFromView.Name);
            return View("City", movieDetail);
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Why can't you do it the same way you pass in the API URI? Possible optimization: Create a class `OpenWeatherApiOptions` with properties `Uri` and `ApiKey`. Fill it from appsettings in startup and inject it in your forecast repo as `IOptions<OpenWeatherApiOptions>` - the details are explained in the docs linked by @galdin

Comment: I have not seen that doc, thank you for sharing! I was getting lost in httpclient/httpclientfactory docs and didn't think to actually read up on the broader context I was working in (i.e., configuration). I ended up using the suggestion in the answer provided. Is there any kind of established preference between the method outlined in the configuration doc and the way demonstrated in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
 public class ForecastRepository : IForecastRepository
{     
   private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
   private readonly string _apiKey;

 public ForecastRepository(HttpClient httpClient, IConfiguration configuration)
 {
     _httpClient = httpClient;   
     _apiKey  = configuration.GetValue<string>("idoWeather");
      //or
     _apiKey  = configuration["idoWeather"];
}
    
 public async Task<CityModel> GetMovieDetailsAsync(string cityName)
  {
    string IDOWeather = _apiKey;

    var queryString = $"data/2.5/weather?q={cityName}&units=imperial&APPID={IDOWeather}";
   var response = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(queryString);
    
             //...code conitnues
    }
```

appsettings:

```
   {
      ....
      "idoWeather": "apikey",
      "openWeatherAPI": "https://api.openweathermap.org/",
    }
```

and by the way I highly recommend you to use HttpClientFactory. if you need httpClient with different url you will have to change baseUrl some way. You can create a set of typed or named http clients in startup, but since you usually will not need all of them, it is better to create when it is needed.
For more info you can read my another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69054959/11392290

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

 public ForecastRepository(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
 {
    _configuration=configuration;
    _clientFactory = clientFactory;
  
}
 
public async Task<CityModel> GetMovieDetailsAsync(string cityName)
  {
 
 var baseAddress = _configuration.GetValue<string>("openWeatherAPI");
   var  IDOWeather = _configuration.GetValue<string>("idoWeather");
      //or
     var baseAddress = _configuration["openWeatherAPI"];
      var  IDOWeather  = _configuration["idoWeather"];

var queryString = $"data/2.5/weather?q={cityName}&units=imperial&APPID={IDOWeather}";

var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
 var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(queryString);
```

to use factory replace

```
 services.AddHttpClient<IForecastRepository, ForecastRepository>(c =>  
 {
     //And Here:
                    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
   }
);
```

with

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

and since you are using a repository you have to add it to services for DI

```
services.AddScoped<IForecastRepository , ForecastRepository>();
```

Comment: He's already using `HttpClientFactory`. `AddHttpClient<>` does the magic here and it's implemented as recommended (at least the part how to get an HttpClient instance) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Thank you for notice.  I just showed to PO  another, IMHO more flexible way. It is up to him what to use.

Comment: Yeah, it just looks to me as if your service can be registered as a "normal" service (and then it should inject the factory) or as a typed http client (and then it should inject the client directly)?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Yes, I updated my answer.

Comment: @Serge Thanks for the answer, that did the trick!

Comment: You know I started off trying to use `HttpClientFactory` as suggested in the answer, but for whatever reason, the code seemed to break with the `.CreateClient()` part. I could only get it to work doing it the way I have it written in the question, but I didn't really understand the difference between the two methods. It sounds like both methods utilize  `HttpClientFactory` and are considered acceptable?

Comment: @AdamCushing You have to add services.AddHttpClient(); in your starup if you want to use factory. See my updated answer. As I pointed already what are going to do if you need http client with another url.? Use factory  has  much more  performance.

Comment: @Serge So I updated the code in my app with the code you provided regarding `HttpClientFactory` but whenever I launch the app and try to load the view for searching the weather forecast, I get this error message: "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WeatherDashEight.Repository.IForecastRepository' while attempting to activate 'WeatherDashEight.Controllers.WeatherController'." I imagine I need to fix something in the controller, so I added the controller code to the question to see if that helps reveal what the problem is

Comment: @AdamCushing You have to add in startup file services.AddScoped<IForecastRepository , ForecastRepository>(); for dependancy injection. See my updated answer

Comment: @Serge Ah! works like a charm now. Thank you so much for patiently walking me through all this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome!